# Scrapy: How to get all strings between two regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I am trying to scrape contents from [this website](http://www.alfie.tokyo/schedule/).
As below, I have a list of all paragraph contains regex "\d+\s(\w{3})".

```
events = response.xpath('//p[re:match(text(), "\d+\s\(\w{3}\)")]').extract()
```

I want a regex to get all text between "\d+\s(\w{3})" and "\d{2}00" from each paragraph excluding the regext matched texts.

Below works, but I want the string in between.

```
for ev in events:
     event_detail = re.search(r'\d+\s\(\w{3}\).*?\d{2}00', ev)
```

I tried below but no luck, an got an error "sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern":

```
for ev in events:
    event_detail = re.search('(?<=(\d+\s\(\w{3}\))(.*?)(\d{2}00)', ev)
    print(event_detail)
```

How could I write a correct regex using lool-behind and look-ahead?

[Solved]
I got rid of "+" in my regex look-behind. Below works perfect.

`for ev in events:
       event_detail = re.search(r'(?<=\d\s\(\w{3}\)).*(?=\d{2}00)', ev)
       print(event_detail)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.alfie.tokyo/schedule/201812.html'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

re.findall('\d+\s\w{3}.*\d{2}:00', soup.prettify())
```

output:

```
['30 1st. 20:00',
 '00 演奏1st. 19:30 2nd. 21:00',
 '30 1st. 20:00',
 '00 演奏1st.19:30 2nd. 21:00']
```

Note: I assume you meant \d{2}:00 not \d{2}00

Comment: Thank you gregory. Do you know how I could get the texts using look-behind and look-ahead?

Comment: Sure, you just add those to your pattern, for example: `re.findall('(?<=:)[\d:]+\s\w{3}.*\d{2}:00.*', soup.prettify())`.  There's nothing special here, just using standard syntax as defined in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html.  As a side note, I wouldn't really do this--since beautiful soup parses the HTML, I'd let the parser do the work of finding elements; see here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find